# How to call one wso2 api from another wso2 api on same server

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a requirement where one wso2 api running on server ( api manager not on local though) say /contextA/1.0/a need to call /contextB/1.0/b running on same server. This can be achieved by calling {{Server}}/contexB/1.0/b using call mediator but the call will go over network. Can this be achieved without the call going over the network?

Comment: Are the context of context/1.0/a and context/1.0/b are the same?

Comment: Not in this case. I will edit it just to be clear.

Comment: It has to go via local network. Localhost should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an in-JVM call, that's not possible. It has to be an HTTP call. The maximum you can do is make the call with `localhost` so that it skips LBs/Reverse Proxies in the front.

Comment: Ok. I thought there was a possibility for in-JVM call. Thanks.